# Vue - how to select just the search results inside dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I' am trying to create a dropdown menu with a small search input and a button to select all options.

What i am trying to do is, i need to search for any word inside the menu and if there any matchs a `Vue` method will filter them out and the button will select just these words not all the menu.

Here is my component:

```
<input id="iBu" type="text" class="form-control" v-model="search" placeholder="Поиск">
<div class="mandragora custom-control custom-checkbox mt-3" v-for="(key, value) in filteredList" :key="value">
    <input class="custom-control-input" type="checkbox" v-model="allChecked" :value="key.id" v-on:click="toggleSelect(value, key.id)" :checked="key.selected">
    <label class="custom-control-label">{{key.name}}</label>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <label>
        <template v-if="!selectAll">
            <input type="checkbox" id="sAll" class="switchButton uk-button uk-button-default" value="Отметить все" v-model="checkAll">
        </template>
    </label>
</div>

<scipt>
export default {
    name: 'main_menu',
    let word = "";
    let maxWords = 500;
    let texts = [];
    let letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    let wordLength = Math.floor(Math.random() * 7) + 3;
    for (var i = 0; i < maxWords; i++){
        let word = "";
        for(var j = 0; j < wordLength; j++) {
            word += letters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length));
        }
        texts.push(
            {
                "id":i,
                "name":word,
                selected: false
            }
        )
    }
    this.randomWords = texts
    data () {
        return {
            username: 'John',
            search: '',
            menuOpened: false,
            selectAll: false,
            selectedItems: 0,
            min_symbols: 3,
            randomWords: null,
            allChecked: [],
            selections: this.randomWords
        }
    },
methods: {
    clickButton: function(){
        if(this.menuOpened == true){
            this.menuOpened = false;
        } else {
            this.menuOpened = true;
        }
    },
    getSelected: function(){
        return this.selections.filter((x,i) => { return x.selected ? x.selected = true: 0; }).length;
    },
    toggleSelect: function(index, id){
        if(this.selections[index].selected){
            this.selections[index].selected = false
        } else {
            this.selections[index].selected = true;
        }
        this.selectedItems = this.getSelected();             
    }
},
computed: {
    checkAll: {
        get: function(){
            return this.selections ? this.allChecked.length == this.selections.length: false;
        },
        set: function(value){
            var allChecked = [];
            console.log(allChecked.length);
            if(value){
                this.selections.forEach(function(item){
                    item.selected = true;
                    allChecked.push(item.id);
                });
            }
            this.allChecked = allChecked;
            this.selectedItems = allChecked.length;
            this.selectAll = true;
        }
    },
    filteredList() {
        if(this.search.length > this.min_symbols){
            return this.selections.filter(item => {
                return item.name.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase());
            })
        } else {
            return this.selections;
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Any suggestions guys!!

Comment: Hi @swordfish do you resolve?, i need the same figure.

Comment: Hey @Mitolo, visit [my github](https://github.com/reznov11/mstlab/tree/master/new_drop/samplevue) and check the **DropDown.vue** component)